# How to import data from excel to textbox?

Tags: excel, vb.net, notimplementedexception

I am trying to import data from Excel to textbox.

I want import data from Excel saved on my C: disk and i get error with System.NotImplementedException
I use library for Excel and Office.

```
Dim ExcelApp As New Excel.Application
Dim ReteilerWorkbook As New WindowsApp1.ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\TR\1.xlsx")
Dim retailerWorksheet As New RetailerWorkbook.Sheets(1)

Private Sub ZPlikuToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ZPlikuToolStripMenuItem.Click

    Me.TextBox1.Text = ""
    TextBox1.Text = retailerWorksheet.cells(1, 1).text
End Sub
```

I want fill textbox1 with data from cell A1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I do on `VB.NET` to import data from `Excel`:

First, I import `Interop` on the head of my `VB` module:

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
```

Then I declare the following **INSIDE** the routine:

```
Private Sub ...
    Dim ExcelApp As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application
    Dim ReteilerWorkbook As Excel.Workbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\TR\1.xlsx")
...
```

Could you try it this way?

To retrieve the `cells(1,1)` content you don't need to declare the `Worksheet`. It doesn't compensate the effort. So you could do this simply with:

```
TextBox1.Text = ReteilerWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1,1).Text
```

And, as always, don't forget to close the workbook at the end:

```
ReteilerWorkbook.Close()
```

Comment: It helps with connection with my Excel saved on disk.

But, how can i copy data from Cell "A1" to textbox1?

My code:     TextBox1.Text = retailerWorksheet.cells(1, 1).text    
Doesn't work. I think that i need another command. Greetings

Comment: Awesome! The last thing, i see that VB "is using" that excel after I close my program. So i can't edit it (Read only mode). How can close excel 1.xlsx with code?

Comment: Okey, maybe you know also how to browse localization of excel instead of constant localization?

Comment: You could look on special folders with the command `Environment.SpecialFolder`. For example, if you're searching on your desktop, the command `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)` will retrieve it's path. Maybe you'll consider to ask another question for your new task?